# Automatically adjusting the width of right container on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, window-resize

In my template, wrapper div hold another two container. One is fixed position left div , and another one is absolute position right div. Right div contain another child div with width 100%.

Html:

```
<div id ="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
     #wrapper {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;background:red;}
 .left {float:left; position:fixed; width:150px; height:100%;background:green;}
.right {position:absolute; width:350px; height:100%; margin-left:150px;background:blue;}
```

My target here is the `right` container. I want to adjust width of this `right div` on window re-size ,so its width remains (view-port width - left div width).

I tried it with jquery:

```
var right_width_prcnt = (($(window).width()- 150)/($(window).width()/100) )

function right_width_adjust() {
         $('.right').stop(false,true).animate({'width':right_width_prcnt + '%'});
};

var resizeTimer = null;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(right_width_adjust, 100);
});
```

Jsfiddle for reference :http://jsfiddle.net/RWDQ2/2/

Is there any css method (without jquery) to adjust width of right div = (window width -left div width)  at all the time whenever we re-size window

Comment: This needs to be worded better, hard to understand what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        var right_width_prcnt = (($(window).width()-150)/($(window).width()/100) );
        $('.right').stop(false,true).animate({'width':right_width_prcnt+ '%'});
    });
});
```

Note: in your code,

```
var right_width_prcnt = (($(window).width()-150)/($(window).width()/100) );
```

was already declared on domready. Meaning, the value remains the same on window resize. It should be recalculated on window resize.

Also, perhaps you should try calculating the percentage like this

```
var right_width_prcnt = (($(window).width()-150)/$(window).width())*100;
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks@Christian ! yeah I think my percentage width value remains same at all the time , Its need to be dynamic, trying it with yours way.

Comment: This adjusting width of right container,as well  as its child element having width=100%, But problem here is that once I re-size it for smaller window and then maximize the window using maximize browser button , width of child element remains at that last position of smaller window .

Comment: Your code working properly , dynamically adjusting width of right container and its child element . But once I clicked browsers maximize button ,right container div goes to initial width. But width of inner element inside this right div remains unchanged.

Comment: on window resize to smaller => width of right div & its child element resizes to smaller,      But ON Browser maximized using browser max button => width of right div resizes accordingly but not its child element and child element remains at smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some manipulation here.

If your left div width is fixed in pixels, then give `width:100%` to the right div and create an inner div for right div and give left margin (value should be equal to the left div width) to the inner div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">zc</div>
      <div class="right">
          <div class="right_inner">xvnxmvn </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0
}
.wrapper { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background:red; 
    float:left
}
 .left {
     width:150px; 
    height:100%;
    background:green; 
    position:fixed
}
.right { 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;  
    background:blue;     
    color:white;
}
.right_inner { 
    margin-left:150px; 
    padding:10px /*Only if you need*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RWDQ2/8/)**

Comment: Thnx@Sowmya---> This is really nice and easy, But my essential style is that left always at fixed position and right is at absolute. Actually left is for the purpose of fixed vertical navigation and right is for content box.

Comment: @galexy left is fixed only there. Chek this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWDQ2/9/)

Comment: thanks again sowmya! But main problem is after removing background green of left you can see right(background:blue) capturing whole screen. That,s what I don't want.

Comment: @galexy That is what I meant as manipulation. Anyway your div will be having an default color so it helps to hide the right div color.